# Storyboard Model Segue: MFMailComposeViewController Hierarchy Issue

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a **viewcontroller A** whose **xib** is in storyboard. **A** is model seque over two other viewcontrollers all in same storyboard.

From viewcontroller **A** I subView a viewcontroller **B**. On viewcontroller **B** there is a button that open **MFMailComposeViewController**.

When **MFMailComposeViewController** appears with progressbar of viewcontroller **A** above it. Actually this progressbar is part of viewcontroller **A**'s Xib.

On cancelling this **MFMailComposeViewController** progressbar shifts to the view behind the **MFMailComposeViewController** and on cancelling that it went back to original viewcontroller **A**

Comment: The question seems to be incomplete

Comment: I solved the issue by presenting it from viewcontroller A, and removing viewcontrollerB's view from superview before presenting viewcontroller A.